# NotificationCenter doesn't pass the data with first loading of the new view but it does every other time

Tags: ios, swift, nsnotificationcenter

hope someone can help me with my issue. I'm quite a beginner programmer and this is my first serious app im trying to build so please be understanding and feel free to point out if i didn't provide enough information or code.

I'm trying to pass data using Notification Controller between View Controllers. Shortly this is how it suppose to work:

After pressing edit button on the MainVC it should pass notification and go to EditVC, where that data should be received and used later on that view.

Problem i stumbled into is that seems EditVC doesn't receive data on first load, but if i go back and press the button again it works flawlessly.
Any suggestion why it doesn't load first time?

I tried to move observer from viewDidLoad to viewDidAppear and notification post to different moment (worth mentioning: for now it gets posted after i long press the cell, what long press achieve is showing additional buttons to edit or delete, i chose this moment because i want to use that notification to pass all data from active cell and will use the same notification in other places too, this specific segue is performing after pressing edit button)like moving it to editButtonPressed function or prepare for segue function, but effect is the same. What am i missing here?

Here are snippets of my code:

Edit VC

```swift
class EditVC: UITableViewController {

override func viewDidLoad() {

        startObserving()
    }

func startObserving() {
        NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(
            self,
            selector: #selector(editPressedName(notification:)),
            name: .editPressedName,
            object: nil
        ) 
    }

@objc func editPressedName(notification: NSNotification) {
        print("\(notification.userInfo) received")
```

MainVC Notification Post

```swift
let activeCellName:[String: Data] = ["name":item!]
print(activeCellName)
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .editPressedName, object: nil, userInfo: activeCellName)
```

Comment: Where and when do you create `EditVC`? It will only receive messages after it's created. Also, this is usually not a good way to pass data around in iOS. For presenting a VC with some data, it's usually better to pass the data to `init()` or in `prepareForSegue()`.

Comment: Can you explain more why it's not good way to pass data using NotificationCenter? I thought if i want to pass one-to-many data its actually the best solution. But like i said i'm just a beginner programmer, so i'm more than happy to be educated in the matter by more experienced people. Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, it's good for one-to-many data passing. But if all you want is to show another VC, than it seems that's just one-to-one.

Comment: oh, thank you for clarification, yeah i want to pass data from one cell to different VC depends on option user choose so i decided that NotificationCenter is probably the way to go. Maybe i should be more clear in my problem description above, sorry about that and thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you press the Edit button for the first time, the `EditVC` it not listening for the notification, as it's `ViewDidLoad` function was not yet called and the observer was not yet set. You can check this by adding a brakepoint to you `startObserving` function and to the Notification post in your first ViewController, and you will see that the notification fires first, and only then the observer is set in your `EditVC`.

To make it work you have to make sure that the `startObserving` is called before the notification was fired. If you are creating the `EditVC` programatically you can move the `startObserving` function into the init:

```
class EditVC: UITableViewController {

    override init(style: UITableView.Style) {
        super.init(style: style)
        startObserving()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
}
```

If you are using storyBoard, you can do something like this

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
    if let destination = segue.destination as? EditVC {
        destination.startObserving()
        // And now you can post the notification
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh great, that's what i was looking for, didn't think about putting startObserving inside prepare(for segue:). Thanks a lot!